# How to Sheets QUERY grouping with "first" aggregate function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to find the balance at the start of a month, dates can be duplicate, though, but I have the records sorted (as they came in, I guess by rowid or something).

I was hoping to do this by a simple `QUERY`...`group by year(date), month(date)` using not `min(date)` (since they can be duplicate) but something like "first()", which is not an aggregate function for google sheets `QUERY` function.

To clarify here an excerpt of the data:

```
2022-01-04 10:57    Passed  155,131.12
2022-01-03 22:33    Passed  155,947.20
2022-01-02 15:05    Passed  157,217.20
2022-01-02 15:05    Passed  164,637.20 <--- that's the balance I want to select (first balance that month)
2021-12-26 9:21     Passed  216,478.73
2021-12-26 9:01     Passed  220,058.73
2021-12-23 20:42    Passed  223,818.73
2021-12-22 19:31    Passed  226,328.73
2021-12-22 13:31    Passed  228,409.23 <--- another balance I want to select (also first balance that month)
```

The problem is simple enough, the solution is tricky, I guess... I tried around a lot, not getting any solution, at least not with `QUERY` and `group by`.  Any help or pointer highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option if you want all the original data displayed is to filter your whole range (you can include as many columns as you need when I say A:C) according to the difference between the end of months of this cell and the subsequent:

```
=FILTER(A:C,BYROW(A:A,LAMBDA(d,EOMONTH(d,0)<>EOMONTH(OFFSET(d,1,0),0))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

```
=index(let(Δ,eomonth(tocol(A:A,1),),
       byrow(unique(Δ),lambda(Σ,{text(Σ,"mmm yy"),xlookup(Σ,eomonth(A:A,),C:C,,,-1)}))))
```

[image]